# How to format numbers in underscore template?

Tags: formatting, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I have an expression in my underscore template like this:

```
'<%= a %> div <%= b %> is <%= a/b %>'
```

I would like to limit the number of decimal counts to a specific number. Is it possible in underscore.js?

Expected:

```
'10 div 3 is 3.33'
```

but actually I see:

```
'10 div 3 is 3.333333333'
```

Comment: The stuff inside `<%= ... %>` is just a JavaScript expression so I think you're really just looking for [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](http://stackoverflow.com/q/610406/479863). [underscore.string](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string) is an Underscore mixin that provides most of what you need and nicely meshes with Underscore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use [`Number.prototype.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

`<%= a %> div <%= b %> is <%= (a/b).toFixed(2) %>`

```js
var tpl, content;
tpl = $('#division-tpl').html();
content = _.template(tpl)({a: 10, b: 3, digits: 2});
$('#content').html(content);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/template" id="division-tpl">
  <%= a %> div <%= b %> is <%= (a/b).toFixed(digits) %>
</script>
<div id="content"></div>
```